# Determine common and distinct nodes between two sorted linked lists recursively

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

Consider following example :
l1, l2, common, unique are 4 linked lists.  Nodes in l1 and l2 are in sorted order. common and unique and empty linked lists.
l1 = 1->3->5->8
l2 = 3->4->8->9
common = null
unique = null

Using iterative method, I figured out that I can easily find common and unique elements as follows:

1. Traverse l1 and l2
2. If l1->data < l2->data, add a new node with l1->data to unique and increment pointer for l1
3. If l1->data > l2->data, add a new node with l2->data to unique and increment pointer for l2
4. If l1->data == l2->data, add a new node with l2->data to common and increment pointers for both l1 and l2.

I can't figure out the recursive approach for this problem.

**Update:**
Both the linked lists can be thought of as set of elements sorted in ascending order. A number can occur at most twice. (Either in both of them, or in exactly one of them, or none of them).

Comment: Note that your iterative algorithm only works if the input lists don't have any runs of equal elements. Every loop is a recursion. Here one way to express it is as a function loop(l1, l2, common, unique) that returns the pair (common, unique) as its answer.  The base case is l1 and l2 empty. This represents the loop's termination. The recursive case represents one iteration of the loop body. It ends with a tail-recursive call that starts the next iteration with the correct new values of the parameters.

Comment: Can a list have consecutive equal elements? For example, is `1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3` a valid list for `l1`?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, the elements in each linked list will be distinct. You can think of it as a set of elements, sorted in ascending order. The example provided by you is not a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, recursive algorithm based on the description that you've added:

```
function get_unique(l1, l2, unique, common):
    if not l1:
        unique -> next = l2
        return
    else if not l2:
        unique -> next = l1
        return
    else if l1 == l2:
        common -> next = new node(with value = l1.value)
        common = common -> next
        l1 = l1 -> next
        l2 = l2 -> next
    else:
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            unique -> next = new node(with value = l1.value)
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            unique -> next = new node(with value = l2.value)
            l2 = l2.next
        unique = unique.next
    get_unique(l1, l2, unique, common)
```